# Php: include files localhost and server: different paths

Tags: php, path, include, organization

let's imagine this situation: your developer directory is something like this:

- project A
- project B
- project C
- common items

the "common items" are common files, classes, functions which are to be used commonly in your project. So in project "X":

```
require_once '../commonitems/mysqlDate.php';
```

and so on. Common items cant be copied multiple times to each projects.
But when you need to upload all of this to directory, it cant be like that. A remote website structure is:

- css
- js
- design
- common
- code

  - code/common

so no outside "common items" directory. How to say "elegant" way to include files different on localhost and remote site? Should I set up "if SERVERNAME == localhost then include X else include Y" looks silly :P

thanx in advance

Comment: Why would you not be able to copy the common files to each directory?  You should have all the files included in the upload as well as the common directory, so all relative path includes should work fine on both localhost and webserver.

Comment: Your development environment should mirror the production environment as much as possible, especially when it comes down to directory structure. However, if you can't, then consider adding the prod/dev 'common' directories to PHP's include path. That'd let you do a simple `include('somefile')` and PHP will take care of actually locating it. As long as the include path is structure such that the `include()` directive works regardless of the environment, then you should be "ok".

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
require_once 'commonitems/mysqlDate.php';
```

and set the PHP include_path to the correct directory on your development environment.